# ERROR in ../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/accordion/accordion.d.ts(1,75): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

I am pretty new to web development, so let me know if more information is required.

I am receiving below error when I try to locally serve my angular app after installing and importing `ng-bootstrap`. The same error is coming up for almost all the parts of `ng-bootstrap`. In addition, some of the bootstrap parts are also giving a similar error, in which, the module `'@angular/forms'` cannot be found either.

> ERROR in
>   ../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/accordion/accordion.d.ts(1,75):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'

- I am running angular CLI 7.1.4 globally and 7.1.2 locally.
- I have already tried re-installing angular.
- I am using Visual Studio Code 1.17 to edit the code and node.js to
  serve.

Comment: be sure you are include import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
and imports [NgbModule] in **all** the modules that have components that use ng-bootstrap